# Doubts about Gradient and Matrices derivatives

Tags: neural-networks, linear-algebra, gradient

Studying NN and I wanted to grasp from scratch the theory of gradient descent and matrices derivatives, so I took a simple scenario and tried to apply gradient ascent and see if everything made sense.
I took a simple linear function $f(x): Ax$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ whose gradient should simply be:
$$
\nabla f(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} = A
$$

[**Proof:**
$$
\text{if }
A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix} \text{ then } f(x) = Ax = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f_1(x) \\ f_2(x)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 \\ a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2\end{pmatrix} 
$$
then taking the gradient:
$$
\nabla f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix} = A
]$$

And then apply a simple step of gradient ascent to a particular vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and if I am not wrong the correct update should be:
$$
w := w + \nabla f(w) = w + Aw
$$
and this, should be the best direction to follow in order to maximise the $L^2$ norm of my function.

[**EDIT** Here I'm not totally sure, following the gradient (in the right direction) in one variable increase the value of your function, but in two variable? What increase? I would say that increase the $L^2$ norm of my function]

But then I tried  to verify if it was correct that $A$ was indeed the best direction to follow in order to maximise the value of $f(w)$ and with my big and sad surprise I was wrong, here is the python code that I have used to do my test:

I took a simple matrix $A$ and simple starting vector $b$
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad and \quad b = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$

first I normalised $A$ dividing each element by the $L^2$ norm of $A$:
$$
A := A/||A||_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0.21320072 & 0.42640143 \\
 0.85280287 & 0.21320072 \end{pmatrix}
$$

And then I updated $b$:

$$
b_A := b + A*b = ... = \begin{pmatrix} 3.70560573 \\ 5.34520788 \end{pmatrix}
$$

but then I took another matrix $I$:

$$
 I = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and after normalising it I updated $b$

$$
b_I := b + I*b = ... = \begin{pmatrix} 4.12132034 \\ 5.12132034 \end{pmatrix}
$$

And then checking the norms:

$$
||b_A||_2 = 6.5040572808010175
$$
and
$$
||b_I||_2 = 6.5736750327040365
$$

which proves that $b_I$ is greater in norm than $b_A$, i.e. following the direction pointed by $I$ I ended up with a greater value of $f(x)$

Here is the python code that I used

```
import numpy as np

# create the matrices and vector

A = np.array([[1, 2],
         [4, 1]])

b = np.array([2, 3]).T

I = np.array([[0, 1],
          [0, 1]])

# normalize the 2 matrices

A = np.divide(A, np.linalg.norm(A))
I = np.divide(I, np.linalg.norm(I))

# do the gradient update

b_A = b + np.matmul(A, b)
b_I = b + np.matmul(I, b)

# check the norm

print('b_A norm: ', np.linalg.norm(b_A))
print('b_I norm: ', np.linalg.norm(b_I))
```

If anyone can help me understand where I'm wrong that would be very appreciated

Comment: $\nabla f = \mathbf{A}^\top$, not $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: (so should be b_A = b + np.matmul(A.T, b))

Comment: You seem to mix up the gradient of $f$ with that of its norm.

Comment: @JohnMadden I have added a Proof of why I believe it's $A$ and not $A^T$. From my calculations should be that $\frac{\partial Ax}{ \partial x} = A$ while $\frac{\partial x^T A}{ \partial x} = A^T$

Comment: @whuber I have added an EDIT inside my question in order to better clarify what I mean by increasing the $L^2$ norm of the function, if it does not sound correct could you please me where I'm wrong?

Comment: $\nabla f$ is indeed $\mathbf{A}$ as you described, but in the chain rule you need to plug in the transpose of that, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724359/does-there-exist-a-gradient-chain-rule-for-this-case (so give the code I provided a shot).

Comment: It just doesn't work out.  The norm of your function defines a scalar-valued function on $\mathbb R^2.$ Thus, the gradient of the norm is a *vector,* not a matrix, and your update ought to consist of adding (some scalar multiple of) this vector to the current solution.